# Using Session values inside VBScript

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, session-variables

This is an excerpt from an old authentication technique.  I'm trying to assign a different value to the `Document.Form.XXXXX.Value` variables.  The values I want are stored inside a Session variable from a separate .asp file.

**Is there any way to use classic ASP Sessions inside VBScript?  Or is there any way to store the Session variables' values in such a way that they can be used inside a VBScript block?**

```
<script language="VBScript" type="text/vbscript">
    ...
Document.Form.txtUniqueID.Value = Auth.QuicklookID
Document.Form.txtUserID.Value = Auth.NTUserID
Document.Form.txtDomain.Value = Auth.NTDomain
Document.Form.txtUsername.Value = Auth.UserName
Document.Form.txtBusinessName.Value = Auth.BusinessName
Document.Form.submit()
    ...
</script>
```

Any help or clarification will help immensely, I'm a newcomer to VBScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you are trying to assign client side inputs (through a click event perhaps) with server side values?  Assuming so, you need to wrap the session values with the `<%= %>` tags.

Try something like this:

```
<script language="VBScript" type="text/vbscript">
    ...
Document.Form.txtUniqueID.Value = "<%=Auth.QuicklookID%>"
Document.Form.txtUserID.Value = "<%=Auth.NTUserID%>"
Document.Form.txtDomain.Value = "<%=Auth.NTDomain%>"
Document.Form.txtUsername.Value = "<%=Auth.UserName%>"
Document.Form.txtBusinessName.Value = "<%=Auth.BusinessName%>"
Document.Form.submit()
    ...
</script>
```

Comment: Yep, just wrap the values with double quotes. :)